# Not All Code Paths Return A Value (C#)

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I'm currently learning C# and I'm having trouble with this program. I'm learning about methods and classes and I'm making a test program that adds two numbers together and displays them in the console. I receive the following three errors:

```
prog.cs(5,13): error CS0161: `Test.addNumbers(int, int)': not all code paths return a value
prog.cs(16,3): error CS0118: `Test.addNumbers(int, int)' is a `method' but a `type' was expected
prog.cs(17,7): error CS0841: A local variable `numbers' cannot be used before it is declared
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public int addNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
    int result;
    result = num1 + num2;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 2;
        int r;

        addNumbers numbers = new addNumbers();
        r = numbers.addNumbers(a, b);

        Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
```

I've tried everything that I know of, but as I said, I'm still learning so I don't know much about C#. Can anyone please explain to me what the errors mean, why they occurred and how to fix them? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `addNumbers` to return a value. Function signature states it returns `int`, so you must return `int` from the function.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static int addNumbers(int num1, int num2) 
   {
    int result;
    result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 2;
        int r;


        r = addNumbers(a, b);

        Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You need `addNumbers numbers = new addNumbers();` only if your function is not static.

Static functions can be called with `ClassName.FunctonName`, while non/static (instance functions) need to be called in a way you described.

```
addNumbers numbers = new addNumbers();
numbers.SomeFunction();
```

You can look it following way.

```
Classname.SomeStaticVariable = 2;
```

Way described above, `SomeStaticVariable` would be same for the entire application at any point. While way described below would be available only while `obj` exists in the memory.

```
Classname obj = new ClassName();
obj.SomeVariable = 2;
```

Comment: Wow, I totally knew that but it never crossed my mind. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @FVNTUM, i've modifed your code a bit. Check my answer. I have changed your addNumbers function to be static, so you can call it within Main() scope.

Comment: No need for `addNumbers numbers = new addNumbers();` ??

Comment: No - addnumbers is a method. You don't instantiate methods - only classes.

Answer (score 0):

Make the method AddNumbers(int a, int b) static so you can use it in the main method.
Edit AddNumbers(int a, int b):
`public int addNumbers(int num1, int num2) 
{
   return num1 + num2;
}`

After that just use the method this way:
r = AddNumbers(a, b);